# How to show error on POST action in an ActionCard?

Tags: azure, post, azure-functions, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm facing a problem I don't know how to solve. I developed an Azure Function that posts a message on a Teams channel with some information about issues. I've also added some action buttons for allowing Teams users to perform an automatic action like assign responsible to that issue. This button, the assign responsible one, is defined to make an "HttpPOST" action to another Azure Function.

[image: Action Card code]

As you can imagine, `assignResponsibleUrl` variable contains the URL of the target Azure Function. The problem comes when the user hits the button that returns an error but without any kind of description to understand what is wrong on this call. I tried the Azure Function target url with several tools like *Postman* and *RESTer* and works fine so, I don't know how to trace the error.

Here you have the error screenshot (sorry about the message but it's in spanish):

[image: Error screenshot]

As you can see, the message says: "The requested action could not be completed. Try it again later." and isn't any descriptive.

Can you help me determine what I'm doing wrong with the ActiveCard declaration or how can I trace the Teams error when hitting the button?

Comment: You may have already done this, but what happens if you debug the Azure Function? Can you determine if it's getting an error and returning a non-success status code?

Comment: Well, I didn't take this approach but checked the console log on the portal. I've checked the messages calling the Azure Function from Postman so messages appeared and then, clicking the Teams button but nothing appeared. I have to say that I have a "context.log" statement as the first line in the Azure Function. So, with these facts I determine that event the Azure Function is being called from Teams.

Comment: Ah, so the Azure function isn't receiving the POST. Is your Azure function deployed to Azure and are you using an HTTPS url?

Comment: Yes both questions. And I tried with body parameters only and query parameters only, and even with no parameters at all.

Comment: Another thing I tried after reviewing documentation is setting Authentication header to empty and null and didn't work either

Comment: Yeah I don't think the auth header would cause this. I'll forward this to some Teams folks to see if they have any pointers for you.

Comment: Do you know how I'm able in some way to determine the response I'm receiving, like the http status code or headers or any other information?

Comment: @jaloplo - can you please share the Post request that is getting generated on button click?

Comment: Here you have: https://issuesmgmtapp.azurewebsites.net/api/SetIssueType?code=hLoPk1Raa8fBECmWJPcOOZ3SpDhHQaXiS5jit//Qe1jgVEwTsup6wQ==&id=139'&type=technical

Comment: @jaloplo - The posted URL is not working for me. can you please try this in Teams web browser and inspect if you see any error and post it to me. Can you please share your manifest.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT, I tried it with Postman and Insomnia plus the Azure portal and worked fine. Let me share the url again for avoiding paste problems in my previous comment: [https://issuesmgmtapp.azurewebsites.net/api/SetIssueType?code=hLoPk1Raa8fBECmWJPcOOZ3SpDhHQaXiS5jit//Qe1jgVEwTsup6wQ==&id=198&type=unknown](https://issuesmgmtapp.azurewebsites.net/api/SetIssueType?code=hLoPk1Raa8fBECmWJPcOOZ3SpDhHQaXiS5jit//Qe1jgVEwTsup6wQ==&id=198&type=unknown)  The method of the request must be "POST" and the response should be the text "success".

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT Here you have the screenshot of [Postman response](https://stackoverflowqa.blob.core.windows.net/azurefunctions/AzureFunctionPostman.png?sp=r&st=2019-06-25T09:28:22Z&se=2019-12-01T18:28:22Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=EME25dZJmP7Rf0h%2FxiO8eqXNZ0wwXzzEJgqvDebmcGM%3D&sr=b).

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT, any update going on here? I'm really interested in know what's happening.

Comment: @jaloplo - Azure function works fine from Postman. There is some issue in card code or the request that is getting generated when you call this Azure function from Card. Easiest way for me to check this is to check your card json. can you please share card json.